# I think my code is correct but I keep getting zero?

Tags: java, while-loop

Output that I want: 10 20 30 40 50..............
   Output that I get: 0

```
public class HelloWorld
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   final int n = 50;
   int i= 0;
    while(i <= n && i % 10 == 0 )
    {
      System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us in words what your code does?

Comment: Step through your code mentally and tell us what each step does.

Comment: First iteration (i = 0): `while` clause it true and it prints `0`. Second iteration (i = 1): `while` clause is false because `i % 10 == 0` is false, and loop ends.

Comment: Andreas should I make ann if clause for the i % 10 == 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(i <= n && i % 10 == 0 )
```

This is the continuation condition which is two expressions connected by logical-and `&&`.

That means *both* must be true for the whole thing to be true.

Now work out the two sub-expressions for when `i` becomes `1`. The first will be true but not so the second (`1` is not a multiple of `10`), meaning the loop will exit at that point. That explains why you're only seeing `0`.

To fix it, you need to separate the two sub-expressions since the loop control depends *only* on the first. However, you still only want *printing* to happen for multiples of ten (the second).

So, assuming as per your desired output `10 20 30 40 50`, you *don't* want `0` as one of the outputs (despite it being, after all, a multiple of 10), the following pseudo-code will do the trick:

```
set n to 50, i to 1
while i is less than or equal to n:
    if the remainder when i is divided by 10 is 0:
        output i
    increment i
```

If you *do* want `0` included in the output, simply set `i` to `0` initially, and you'll see `0 10 20 30 40 50`.

I've left the code above as pseudo-code on the assumption this is classwork of some description - it should be relatively easy to turn that into any procedural language.

Comment: Thank you.. now I understand why:))

Answer (score 1):

```
i % 10 == 0
```

This will evaluate to false on the second loop so the while wont continue. I think you want this...

```
    final int n = 50;
    int i= 0;
    while(i <= n)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

This allows i to increment all the way up to n, but it will only print results when `i % 10 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `while` and both a `while` and an `if`. Try

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int n = 50;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
      if (i % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eli, you might want to clean up that first sentence. OP is not *using* both while/if, I assume you meant they *should* be using that.

Answer (score 0):

Loop run for once only for i=0. That's it.